# Redhat Fuse bundle takes a lot of time to start due to several cxf rsServer endpoints

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, cxfrs

We're using camel  component for exposing several REST services through our Integration Layer. We are using Redhat Fuse for deploying our bundle.

And the problem is, after deployment of the bundle(created state), it takes around 45 minutes for the bundle to be completely up(started state) as we have more than 20  endpoints. I can see all the  endpoints take approx. 2 minutes to be published, and they're published sequentially.

So is there any way I can make all my endpoints to be published simultaneously, rather than one-by-one?

Camel version: 2.16
Redhat Fuse version: 6.2.0

Comment: You have 20 endpoints in a single bundle? Why not break this up  into several bundles instead..

Comment: I do understand we could group the endpoints into different bundles, but wanted to know whether we can publish the endpoints simultaneously irrespective of the number of endpoints in the bundle.

The single bundle design was chosen during initial phases of the project, can't recall as to why.

Comment: I think each route has a number which indicates the startup order. I am not sure they can be started simultaneously due to this. Perhaps a Camel developer can provide more detail. However, even with 20 endpoints, why is it taking 45 min to start? The endpoints shouldn't take more than 1-2 min at the top.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti - As each endpoint is taking approx 2 mins to start, and it's happening on-by-one. So almost 40-45 mins in all.

Comment: Is this the paid version of Fuse? Then why not ask Red Hat about this?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti - Perhaps, [claus](http://stackexchange.com/users/176018/claus-ibsen) could answer it better then.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti - Nope.